# Small red round delete buttons

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, button, uibutton

How can I create one of these small red round delete buttons like in the safari app (at the top and left of a tab)?
Is it a default UIButton with an image or an pre-defined button of the iOS SDK?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make the close icon (red x) on the view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714535/how-to-make-the-close-icon-red-x-on-the-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it somewhere 
http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/6804/buttoniry.png

I think there is no such pre-defined button of the iOS SDK